# What's wrong with this JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').live('submit', function(){
      $('#template').tmpl([{ "id" : "555" }, { "in" : "checked" }   ]).prependTo('#content');
   });
});
```

with and with HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text-x-jquery/template" id="template"> 
      <form action="" method="post">
      "${id}" <div class="cellData cellRadios"> <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" "${in}"/> </div>
      </form>
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="" method="post">
  <input value="Save" type="submit">
  </form>

  <br><br>

  <div id="content"> </div>
```

then Error Console in Firefox says Syntax Error in line 1 of `jquery.tmpl.min.js` which is from [JQuery.tmpl()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

JSFiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/Cu5Mj/4/

Is it

```
$('#template').tmpl([{ "id" : "555" }, { "in" : "checked" }   ]).prependTo('#content');
```

that is wrong?

**Update** Updated JSFiddle and post with code that fails.

Comment: @Sandra: Your fiddle works fine, I see "555" appear before the form is posted...

Comment: You are right. What is going on here! I must have simplified the problem too much. http://jsfiddle.net/Cu5Mj/3/

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It's writes 555 below the Save button, but no error. Have you checked to make sure your browser has the tmpl file downloaded correctly? (note, that's both of the fiddles.)

Comment: Posting a fiddle that works seems daft.

Comment: Okay. Now I have found and added the broken code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the followings in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template">
    <form action="" method="post">
        "${Id}" <div class="cellData cellRadios"> <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" ${In} /> </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

and your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').live('submit', function(){
      $('#template').tmpl({ "Id" : "555","In" : "checked" }).prependTo('#content');
       return false;
   });
});
```

and it works for me now.

The problems I think was the template variable names, I capitalized them, and the template data was an array of 2 objects instead of a simple object. (Also changed the template script MIME a bit.)

Comment: the problem was especially **in**, it's a reserved word in javascript : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words